# BlackBerry Dynamics SDK for iOS v. 8.1.0.37 and Firebase analytics crash the application on iOS 14

Tags: ios, blackberry, blackberry-dynamics

We have integrated BlackBerry Dynamics SDK to our iOS application which is also using Firebase analytics. Everything is working fine in devices running iOS 12/13, but on devices running iOS 14 the application crashes when initialising Firebase.

The BlackBerry authorisation goes fine and once user is authorised then the code initialising Firebase is being executed and crash happens.

BlackBerry Dynamics SDK version is 8.1.0.37 and we are using the dynamic library instead of the static library.

BlackBerry Dynamics docs says the following:

> SDK version 8.1 is required to support FirebaseCore for apps on iOS
> 14. FirebaseCore is not compatible with SDK version 8.0 or lower on iOS 14. The FirebaseCore pod should be removed if it is not being used
> by the app.

Here is the call stack:

```
#0  __exceptionPreprocess ()
#1  objc_exception_throw ()
#2  -[NSProxy methodSignatureForSelector:] ()
#3  ___forwarding___ ()
#4  _CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
#5  +[ACSubclasser wrapObjectIntoSubclass:] ()
#6  +[NSURLSession(ACURLProtocol) ac_rawSessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] ()
#7  +[NSURLSession(ACURLProtocol) miac_sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] ()
#8  ___lldb_unnamed_symbol9442$$BlackBerryDynamics ()
#9  ___lldb_unnamed_symbol9444$$BlackBerryDynamics ()
#10 -[FIRInstallationsAPIService initWithAPIKey:projectID:]
#11 -[FIRInstallationsIDController initWithGoogleAppID:appName:APIKey:projectID:GCMSenderID:accessGroup:]
#12 -[FIRInstallations initWitAppOptions:appName:]
#13 -[FIRInstallations initWithApp:]
#14 __40+[FIRInstallations componentsToRegister]_block_invoke
#15 -[FIRComponentContainer instantiateInstanceForProtocol:withBlock:]
#16 -[FIRComponentContainer instanceForProtocol:]
#17 +[FIRComponentType instanceForProtocol:inContainer:]
#18 +[FIRInstallations installationsWithApp:]
#19 +[FIRInstallations installations]
#20 +[FIRAnalytics updateFirebaseInstallationID] ()
#21 +[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] ()
#22 -[FIRApp configureCore]
#23 +[FIRApp addAppToAppDictionary:]
#24 +[FIRApp configureWithName:options:]
#25 +[FIRApp configureWithOptions:]
#26 +[FIRApp configure]
#27 -[MFAppDelegate finalizeApplicationLaunch]
#28 -[MFAppGDDelegate didAuthorize]
#29 -[MFAppGDDelegate onAuthorized:]
#30 -[MFAppGDDelegate handleEvent:]
#31 __NSThreadPerformPerform ()
#32 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#33 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 ()
#34 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#35 __CFRunLoopRun ()
#36 CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#37 GSEventRunModal ()
#38 -[UIApplication _run] ()
#39 UIApplicationMain ()
#40 main
#41 start ()
```

And here is what is printed to the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSProxy methodSignatureForSelector:] called!'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a619d114 0x1b99c3cb4 0x1a745f3f8 0x1a619f2e4 0x1a61a16cc 0x1103d3540 0x11036960c 0x110369320 0x1042370f8 0x104237680 0x100e83ed4 0x100e896e8 0x100e825d4 0x100e82428 0x100e82320 0x100e35a50 0x100e35cd8 0x100e36358 0x100e82dd0 0x100e82d08 0x1015c3f84 0x1015c3eb0 0x100e30e74 0x100e309d4 0x100e2fd54 0x100e2f778 0x100e2f6cc 0x10087eeec 0x100b5e7a8 0x100b5eaf0 0x100b5e6ac 0x1a747cda0 0x1a611d240 0x1a611d140 0x1a611c488 0x1a6116a40 0x1a6116200 0x1bc211598 0x1a89dc004 0x1a89e15d8 0x1008a228c 0x1a5df5598)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSProxy methodSignatureForSelector:] called!'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out that the crash happens only when MobileIron's AppConnect SDK is being linked to the application as well.

So we were able to solve the issue by removing AppConnect SDK from the BlackBerry Dynamics version of our application.

Answer (score 0):

The dylib and static should be the same in this case. Recommend contacting the BlackBerry support team to look into if the issue persists.